What are the options to refinish (or in any other way solve scratches/wear) this floor
I asked a builder and they suggested whitewashing and that there are very few options, since it seems to be a maple floor. But when they showed me pictures of whitewashed maple floor, I don't like them. Any other ways I could make this floor look new? It has some scratches/stains/wear.

More pictures: https://imgur.com/a/G0urJ6j

The other pictures should be put here as well. Imgur is demanding I turn off my ad blocker, and that's a no-go on that site. Please use the Edit link and Mountain icon to add the pictures.

Are you sure this is a wood floor and not actually a laminate surface? Laminate can be scratched, but it cannot be sanded.

When doing a wood floor, there are two main options:

Sand and refinish.
Screen and recoat.

A screen and recoat removes most of the polyurethane cover and leaves all the wood.  If all your damage is in the polyurethane cover, it should fix it.  If oil or ammonia based cleaners have been used on the floor, there is a cleaning step that is critical.  If not cleaned, ammonia or oil can be embedded in the polyurethane layer, causing the top of the polyurethane not to stick to the bottom.  Fixing that is difficult and may require a full sand and refinish (now harder because the floor is unevenly coated).
A sand and refinish removes all of the polyurethane cover and some of the wood.  It may be needed if some of the damage is to the wood itself, not just the polyurethane cover.  The sanding step will clean off any oil or ammonia residue.  This also allows changing the finish color.
You can do an infinite number of screens and recoats.  Since they don't touch the wood, you're just fixing the polyurethane cover.  Each sand and refinish takes away some of the wood.  Eventually you don't have enough left.
At first glance, the screen and recoat may seem easier (a sand and refinish includes screen and recoat steps).  However, the cleaning step makes it harder to do correctly.  The sand and refinish is easier to perform but does "damage" the wood (in the sense that there is less wood afterwards).
Note that if there is damage to the underlying wood, a screen and recoat won't fix it.  It can only fix damage to the polyurethane cover.  A stain is an example of something that has probably damaged the underlying wood.  Scratches or even wear may also get down into the wood layer.  If so, the fix is a full sand and refinish.  Ideally you'd catch damage like that before it got through the polyurethane, but life isn't always ideal.
Whitewashing can mean different things.  They may sand or screen first or they may just whitewash over the existing polyurethane.  I would be reluctant to work with someone who claimed that whitewashing without sanding would fix scratches, wear, or even staining.  It might cover the stain or the stain might show through (as the wood grain does).

This is good advice and I upvoted, but I think that no advice on finishing hardwood floors is complete without a big warning: the sanding step is very difficult to get right, and better left to pros. I'm a pro and I've damaged my good share of floors. It takes a lot of practice and knowledge and control of the machines. For DIY, a light sanding a poly on top is totally doable and riskless.

Normally, one would have the floor sanded and then refinished with a clear coat. Even if it's an engineered wood floor, there's usually enough real wood to lightly sand.
